# Можно ли использовать транзакции с целью обеспечить асинхронность

Tags: c#, ado.net

Возможно под транзакцией подразумевать асинхронность?
Если два проекта одновременно запустить и поочередно выполнять

Задание

> Создайте хранимую процедуру для базы данных ShopDB, способную просматривать информацию о продуктах по ID продукта. Создайте приложение по шаблону ConsoleApplication, способное продемонстрировать работу этой процедуры. Для передачи значений параметрам процедуры используйте объект SqlParameter. Команду, вызывающую процедуру для получения информации о продукции следует выполнить асинхронно. Нельзя использовать async.

Comment: Нет, асинхронность и транзакция это как теплое с мягким - совсем разные вещи.

Comment: `Команду, вызывающую процедуру для получения информации о продукции следует выполнить асинхронно. Нельзя использовать async.` вас по сути попросили использовать EAP/APM вместо TAP, см [Шаблоны асинхронного программирования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/)

Comment: Вы эти задания откуда берёте? Если препод даёт - уточните у него, что именно использовать. Но, возможно, вы какой-то самоучитель/курс используете. И вероятно, несколько устаревший. Поделитесь с нами.

Comment: https://itvdn.com/ru/video/ado-net/using-sqlcommand

Comment: (｀㊥益㊥)Ψ Кстати можно поржать над преподом и сделать таки используя Task-и, но не используя async